# How to write a constraint such that 1 task done by only 1 worker | Google OR-Tools| Scheduling Problem

Tags: python, constraints, scheduled-tasks, or-tools, cp-sat

I am using google OR-Tools to solve a scheduling problem.

The setup has 6 shifts, 3 tasks, and 3 workers. (Numbers can change in the future.)

Workers are named A, B, C.

Quantity means how many shifts are required to finish that task.(predefined per task.)

I want to write a constraint such that task-1 is done by only 1 worker if possible. And 1 worker can not do multiple tasks in the same shift/time.

**How can I write such a constraint using google OR-Tools?**

---

#### Sample code

```py
import pandas as pd
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

""" Inputs """
num_workers = 3
num_shifts = 6
task_info = {
    "task-1": 3,
    "task-2": 3,
    "task-3": 2,
}

""" Processing """
num_tasks = len(task_info)
quantities = list(task_info.values())

model = cp_model.CpModel()

shifts = {}
maximize_this = 0
for t in range(num_tasks):
    for s in range(num_shifts):
        for w in range(num_workers):
            shifts[(t, s, w)] = model.NewBoolVar(f't{t} s{s} w{w}')
            maximize_this += shifts[(t, s, w)]


for s in range(num_shifts):
    for w in range(num_workers):
        # Constraint: 1 worker in 1 shift can do at most 1 task of 1 quantity
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(t, s, w)] for t in range(num_tasks)) <= 1)
    for t in range(num_tasks):
        # Constraint: 1 task is done by at most 1 worker in 1 shift
        model.Add(sum(shifts[(t, s, w)] for w in range(num_workers)) <= 1)

# Constraint: 1 task of n quantity is done by 1 worker in n shifts
for t in range(num_tasks):
    model.Add(sum(sum(shifts[(t, s, w)] for s in range(num_shifts))
              for w in range(num_workers)) <= quantities[t])

# Constraint: 1 worker for 1 task if possible
# Need Suggestions

# To complete as many tasks as possible
model.Maximize(maximize_this)

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

""" Output """
if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
    alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    data = []
    for t in range(num_tasks):
        data_i = []
        for s in range(num_shifts):
            s_val = ""
            for w in range(num_workers):
                if solver.Value(shifts[(t, s, w)]) == 1:
                    s_val = f'{alphabets[w]}'
            data_i.append(s_val)
        data.append(data_i)

    data = pd.DataFrame(
        data,
        index=list(task_info.keys()),
        columns=[f'shift-{s}' for s in range(num_shifts)])
    data["quantity"] = quantities

    print(data)
else:
    print("No solution found")
```

---

#### Current Output

|  | shift-1 | shift-2 | shift-3 | shift-4 | shift-5 | shift-6 | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| task-1 | B | B |  |  |  | B | 3 |
| task-2 | C | A |  |  |  | A | 3 |
| task-3 | A |  |  |  | B |  | 2 |

---

#### Expected Output Example

One possible output that I want is shown in the below table.

|  | shift-1 | shift-2 | shift-3 | shift-4 | shift-5 | shift-6 | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| task-1 | A |  | A |  | A |  | 3 |
| task-2 |  | B |  | B |  | B | 3 |
| task-3 | C |  |  | C |  |  | 2 |

---

### Edit 1

After checking cph's answer, I tried writing this but couldn't complete it...

```
for t in range(num_tasks):
    for w in range(num_workers):
        m_this = model.NewIntVar(0, num_shifts, "")
        # model.Add(m_this == sum(shifts[(t, s, w)] for s in range(num_shifts)))
        model.AddMaxEquality(m_this, [shifts[(t, s, w)] for s in range(num_shifts)])

        m_others = model.NewIntVar(0, num_shifts, "")
        # model.Add(m_others == sum(sum(shifts[(t, s, w1)] for s in range(num_shifts)) for w1 in range(num_workers) if w != w1))
        model.AddMaxEquality(m_others, [shifts[(t, s, w1)] for s in range(num_shifts) for w1 in range(num_workers) if w != w1])

        model.AddImplication(m_this, m_others.Not())
```

Answer (score 0):

One question: why does your constraint "1 task of n quantity is done by 1 worker in n shifts" use <= quantities[t] instead of == quantities[t]? Don't you want the number of shifts for the task to exactly equal the quantity?  I guess it's because you are maximizing the number of task steps done during the shifts instead of minimizing the number of shifts required to finish all the defined tasks.

The constraint you are looking for could be expressed in meta-code like this:

```
For each worker w
    For each task t
        Let m_this = maximum value of all the shifts[(t, s, w)] for s = 1 to num_shifts
        Let m_others = maximum value of all the shifts[(t, s, w1)] for s = 1 to num_shifts and w1 = 1 to num_workers, except where w1 = w
        Add the constraint (m_this implies not m_others)
```

I'm a complete layman in Python, but I believe you could get the maximum with `model.AddMaxEquality(m_this, <list of the BoolVar's>)`.

The implication could be added using `model.AddImplication(m_this, m_others.Not())`""

Comment: Thanks for your comment. "using <=" because some data has very few workers or/and shifts to do all the quantity of work. I have some doubts about your suggestion. 1) AddMaxEquality only deals with IntVar instead of BoolVar. 2)maximum value of what? Is it the sum of shifts[(t, s, w)]? So m_this should be initialized as `model.NewIntVar(0, num_shifts, "")`, right?

Comment: BoolVar is derived from IntVar so you can use it wherever an IntVar is required.  shifts[(t, s, w)] is a boolean variable that means "task t is being worked on in shift s by worker w".

Comment: By `all the shifts[(t, s, w)] for s = 1 to num_shifts` I mean a list of shifts variables for a given task t and worker w. If the maximum value of these is 1, it means the worker worked on that task in at least one shift.  By `all the shifts[(t, s, w1)] for s = 1 to num_shifts and w1 = 1 to num_workers, except where w1 = w` I mean all the shifts[] for a given task t which other workers than w worked on it. If the maximum of these is 1, it means another worker worked on the task.

Comment: By making the constraint `(m_this implies not m_others)` it means that if one worker worked on a task, then it must be the case that other workers did not work on it.

Comment: As I mentioned, I've no experience with Python, the code in your edit looks OK, but you could try making m_this and m_other BoolVar instead of IntVar; they only can have the value 0 or 1.

Comment: AddMaxEquality with a list of BoolVar has the effect of a Boolean "or" operation-- it returns 1 if any of the variables is 1, 0 otherwise.